# Knitr: creating a standalone page with animations

Tags: r, animation, knitr

I have an R presentation created using RStudio. I would like to upload it to RPubs (or anywhere!) The document has some animations, created using `fig.show='animate'`. I also use the scianimator package:

`library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(animation.fun = hook_scianimator)`

However, when I knit the presentation from RStudio, the animations are saved in a separate directory. Then if I upload the document to RPubs, the animations aren't uploaded and the slides don't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds? I'm using R 3.1.1, knitr 1.7 and RStudio 0.98.1028 on Mac.

Comment: Duplicate of https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/883?

Comment: Yes, it is... well the issue is a duplicate of this!